# JQuery $.ajax calls success method on timeout, instead of error, running in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I've noticed this weird behaviour of jQuery in Safari. After setting up the call like this:

```
$.ajax( {
    'url' : url,
    'dataType' : 'json',
    data : reqdata,
    timeout: 20000, //10 secs of timeout 
    success : function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        console.log("success");
        if ((data === null) || (data.length == 0)) {
            ts.doAction( {
                'actionName' : 'timeout',
                'request' : {
                    'reqdata' : reqdata,
                    'actionName' : actionName,
                    'url' : url
                },
                'controller' : ts
            });
        }

        ts.doAction( {
            'actionName' : actionName,
            'data' : data
        });
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error: " + textStatus);

        if (textStatus == "timeout") {
            ts.doAction( {
                'actionName' : 'networkFailureError',
                'request' : {
                    'reqdata' : reqdata,
                    'actionName' : actionName,
                    'url' : url
                },
                'controller' : ts
            });
        } else {
            ts.doAction( {
                'actionName' : 'serverError',
                'request' : {
                    'reqdata' : reqdata,
                    'actionName' : actionName,
                    'url' : url
                },
                'controller' : ts
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If a timeout occurs (I switch the local webserver off), the 'success' method will be called! More  than this in the textStatus parameter there is a string with "success" !!! The error handler doesn't even get called.... (As you may notice the only way I had to tell the problem, was to check the data param if it is null or 0 length... Why this behaviour? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.

What I found is that it depends on how long is the timeout. Using chrome, for a timeout less that 2000 miliseconds, everything works as expected, but for greater timeouts, the success handler is not called.

Comment: I ended up writing to the official jquery forum and they filed it as a bug ( a developer wanted me to do some tests and he ended up classifying this as a bug). This was in august anyway and I didn't follow up very well the outcome, if they fixed it or not. I remember anyway that I ended up using some workaround even if I don't remember which one. Soz

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your request is being cached.

Try the `$.ajax` call with the `cache: false` option set.  Per the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> If set to false it will force the
>   pages that you request to not be
>   cached by the browser.

You may also want to verify that your request's response is being cached by viewing the request/response using Firebug, Fiddler or some other web request monitoring tool.

Comment: No way. Even before I was not getting the timeout working... The success handler was called and data body was null. Is this behaviour related to safari???